# Subversive and Eclipse - after commit, it still shows outgoing changes

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

when using Subversive in Eclipse and committing my outgoing changes to my repo, often eclipse still shows the files as it seems that they have outgoing changes.

Restarting Eclipse solves the problem. The same happens in the Team Synchronizing perspective, even after selecting "Remove current synchronization" from Synchronize popup menu.

I'm using latest Eclipse Indigo (build id 20110615-0604) with Polarion conenctors for SVN 1.6.

Any idea's what is causing this?

Thanks!
Ronald

Comment: Have any of these answers helped you? You got some votes for your question so it would be nice to get some feedback on the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this happen before. Unfortunately the only way I've found to fix it is to do a Team -> Synchronise on another project, then go back to your original project(s).

This works if you have synchronised your whole workspace too. Just sync one of your projects then go back and sync the whole workspace again.

Not nice but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse Indigo is distributing a version with known bugs.  See here:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329555

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `svn cleanup`. Not sure where that is in subversive.

I also recommending [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org) for a svn eclipse combo.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions didn't work for me, but I have solved this by updating Subversive. In

`Settings` - `Install/Update` - `Available Software Sites`

I've activated *Subversive Site* (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/), then a simple `Help`- `Check for updates`. I'm not sure if the update site is available on all Eclipse versions, maybe you have to add the site manually.